# Custom DependencyProperty on Style.Trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, dependency-properties, multitrigger

for an `UserControl` I declared a `DependencyProperty` :

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DeselectedPresentationModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DeselectedPresentationMode",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPresentationModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedPresentationMode",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Now I want to use these properties within a MultiTrigger:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" x:Key="MyUserControlItemStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="gui:MyUserControl.DeselectedPresentationMode" Value="0" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PresentationModeIconOnly}" />
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="gui:MyUserControl.DeselectedPresentationMode" Value="1" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PresentationModeSimple}" />
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="gui:MyUserControl.SelectedPresentationMode" Value="0" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PresentationModeExtended}" />
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="gui:MyUserControl.SelectedPresentationMode" Value="1" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PresentationModeIconOnly}" />
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    ...
    ...
    <ListBox ... ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyUserControlItemStyle}"/>
```

But if I use MyUserControl another project, there is no reaction if I change my `DependencyProperty`. Whether I use `xaml` e.g:

```
<Window 
...
x:Class="WpfControlsTester.MainWindow" 
Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <GUI:MyUserControl Name="test"/>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding SelectedPresentationMode, ElementName=test}" />
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding DeselectedPresentationMode, ElementName=test}" />
</Grid>
```

or if I use any kind of manipulation the value like            `this.test.DeselectedPresentationMode = 0;` on an event or smth else.

I used WPF Inspector to "debug" my Triggers, and both properties always had their default value (1). Where is my mistake or what should I add to update my triggers?

Edit : Changed false "MyControl to "MyUserControl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the MultiDatatrigger instead like this in order to get the property changes:

```
<Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DeselectedPresentationMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyUserControl}}}" Value="0" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PresentationModeIconOnly}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me. I also tried MultiDataTrigger, but I get an exception like "Property"-Binding should not be null. Maybe I implemented it on the wrong way :-)

Answer (score 1):

This *could* just be a copy and paste error, but in your code example where you declare the `Dependency Properties`, your control is named `MyUserControl`, but in the other code examples, it is called `MyControl`. These names will need to match if you want this to work.

UPDATE >>>

Ok, I thought that might be the case... so, moving on... can you see the property value if you simply bind to it?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPresentationMode, ElementName=test}" />
```

If you can, then we can move on... usually when a binding does not work, there is a line that starts with the word `Error` output into the `Output Window` in Visual Studio. What does your error say. if you have one? (You *may* need to turn this functionality on by going to Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings and setting the `Data Binding` option to `Warning` or `Error`.)

If you have no error in the Output Window, this could be trickier to debug. Let me know.

Comment: Sry, as expected it was only a c&p error, so on productive code this cannot be my mistake.